# Difference between scanf("%d",((*a+i)+j)) and scanf("%d",&a[i][j])

Tags: c, arrays

As per as my understanding a[i][j] can be read like  *(*a+i)+j , but i scan scan with two of these notation , i see differences , below is the code snippet,

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
    //      scanf("%d",((*a+i)+j));
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            printf("Address of &a[%d][%d]=%ld , Adress of ((*a+%d)+%d)=%ld\n",i,j,&a[i][j] ,i,j, ((*a+i)+j));
        }
    }
```

i get below output ,

```
1
Address of &a[0][0]=140736658532752 , Adress of ((*a+0)+0)=140736658532752
2
Address of &a[0][1]=140736658532756 , Adress of ((*a+0)+1)=140736658532756
3
Address of &a[0][2]=140736658532760 , Adress of ((*a+0)+2)=140736658532760
4
Address of &a[1][0]=140736658532772 , Adress of ((*a+1)+0)=140736658532756
5
Address of &a[1][1]=140736658532776 , Adress of ((*a+1)+1)=140736658532760
6
Address of &a[1][2]=140736658532780 , Adress of ((*a+1)+2)=140736658532764
7
Address of &a[2][0]=140736658532792 , Adress of ((*a+2)+0)=140736658532760
8
Address of &a[2][1]=140736658532796 , Adress of ((*a+2)+1)=140736658532764
9
Address of &a[2][2]=140736658532800 , Adress of ((*a+2)+2)=140736658532768
```

can someone , please shed some light on the memory representation for two cases ....

Comment: It's `(*(a+i)+j)`. Note the position of the inner parenthesis. Also, print pointers with `%p`. Using `%ld` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said,

> As per as my understanding a[i][j] can be read like *(*a+1)+j , but i scan scan with two of these notation , i see differences , below is the code snippet,

I assume you had a typo. You meant `*(*a+i)+j` instead of `*(*a+1)+j`.

However, that is not true either.

`a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a+i)`, not `(*a+i)`. Due to operator precedence, `*a+i` is equivalent to `(*a)+i`, not `*(a+i)`.

Similarly, `a[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(*(a+i)+j)`, not `*(*a+1)+j`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple precedence issue. `(*a+1)` should be `*(a+1)`.

Otherwise it's equivalent to: `(*(a+0)+i+j)`.